# Single multi-tenanted firestore or many single tenanted firestores?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a SaaS system that allows users to define their own data models and enter data according to those models.  It's a bit like airtable.

One user might model a bookshop, and would have a `Book` model, with title and ISBN fields.  Another user might model medical records, and would have "date of last visit" as a field.

In the case of the bookshop, I want users to be able to search on title and ISBN.  In the case of the medical records, I want users to be able to search on the date of the last visit.

I am using Firestore as my backend.

Firestore requires an index to enable a search.  So that approach will not scale as # of customers increases.

My thought therefore was to have a Firestore instance for each customer, and those specific instances would have the necessary indexes.

I'm sure there are downsides to doing this though.

What would folks recommend to best solve this need?

Comment: You'll need a search in all products, or you'll need a search in each category of products? Can two users have two different Book models?

Comment: Yes they could @alex-mamo.  One bookstore, Hogans Books, would model books their own way - title, ISBN, number of pages, and 4 pictures -  and would enter their own list of books.  Mamos Books might have a completely different model title, 2 pictures, author, year of publication etc - and enter books according to that model.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. So the basic idea is that if someone selects a model without a title for example, and when someone searches by title, then those results won't be listed as results, right?

Comment: Kind of.  Hogans Bookshop will not see the models that Mamos Bookshop has defined.  Say Hogan defines title in their book model.  They will be able to search by title.  Mamos do not define title in their book model (for example).  So they will not get the option to search by title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is some kind of weird, since you will not provide at least a few standard common properties for each user of your Bookshop.

When you want to perform a search in a Cloud Firestore database, you need the exact name of the property on which you want to search for. Having dynamic properties might not help you solve the search feature. However, you can create a document with a property of type array that can hold the name of all properties the users have chosen and perform a search on every property, but this solution will be much too expensive.

In my opinion, a possible solution might be to create at least a few common properties, so you can have the properties on which you can search. When someone creates, for example, a book shop you can display at the beginning all available properties a user can choose. Once you create a shop, you can have different users with different shop properties. This means that if a user does not choose a property, when you perform a search on that property, the results won't contain his/her products. This will work, **only** if you have predefined properties.

Comment: Alex, my question really is balancing the choice of a) doing something like you suggest above or b) standing up a firestore per customer.

Comment: IMHO, if I were you, I'll go ahead with the solution that exists in the last part of my answer. But it's up to you to decide which is better for you. Maybe when you launch the project, add a comment and tell me how it works and which solution you choose.